# Find the parity of the cardinality of a set

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, quadratic-residues

Let $p$ be an odd prime and let
$$P:=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{N}\times \mathbb{N}: 0<x<\frac{p}{2},0<y<\frac{p}{2},x^2+y^2=1\pmod{p}\}$$
Prove that #$P$ is odd if and only if $p=\pm 1\pmod{8}$.

$\textbf{Solution}$ Let $T$ be the involution defined as $T(x,y):=(y,x)$. Then $T(P)=P$, so that the parity of #$P$ is equal to the parity of the subset $P_0$ of elements of $P$ which are fixed by $T$. These elements are of the form $(x,x)$ with $2x^2=1\pmod{p}$, and $0<x<\frac{p}{2}$. The congruence admits solutions if and only if $p=\pm 1\pmod{8}$, by the quadratic reciprocity law. When a solution $\overline{x}$ exists, there is only one more solution modulo $p: -\overline{x}$. The claim follows because exactly one of the points $(\overline{x},\overline{x})$ and $(-\overline{x},-\overline{x})$ belongs to $P_0$.

What I can't understand:

1) I know that the congruence $x^2=2\pmod{p}$ has a solution iff $\left(\frac{2}{p}\right)=1$ and this happens iff $p=\pm1\pmod{8}$. Why do the same hold for $2x^2=1\pmod{p}$?

2) What does it mean the last part of the Solution? It means that #$P_0=1$?

Comment: $2x^2\equiv 1 \pmod{p}\iff x^2 \equiv \frac{p+1}{2}\pmod{p}$, and $\left(\frac{a}{p}\right) = \left(\frac{2^2a}{p}\right)$.

Comment: Alternatively note the group structure here, multiplying a non-residue and a residue cannot give a residue. Since $x^2$ and $1$ are definitely residues we must have that $2$ is a residue...i.e. $p\equiv \pm 1 \bmod 8$.

Comment: Viewed in another way we know that $1$ is a residue mod $p$ so we would require $2x^2$ to be...i.e. $\left(\frac{2x^2}{p}\right) = 1$ giving $\left(\frac{2}{p}\right)=1$.

Comment: $P_0$ isn't defined anywhere in the question, so it's hard to know what to make of it.

Comment: @GerryMyerson $P_0$ is the subset of $P$ made by point which are fixed by $T$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The elements $(\overline x,\overline x)$ and $(-\overline x,-\overline x)$ are both fixed by $T$, but exactly one of them belongs to $P$ because of the condition $0\lt x\lt p/2$, $0\lt y\lt p/2$. So, yes, $P_0$ has just one element.